# How I replace a string in a list that contain int and float? in python

Tags: python, string, loops, replace, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean a database. I am extracting each column and cleaning separately with this formula:

```
def Cleaning_strings(Data,Correction):
    for i in range(len(Data)):
        if isinstance(Data[i], float) : 
            Mom_Normal = Data[i]
            Correction.append(Mom_Normal)
        elif isinstance(Data[i], int): 
            Mom_Normal1 = Data[i]
            Correction.append(Mom_Normal1)
        else:
            Zeros = int(Data[i].replace('--','0')) 
            Correction.append(Zeros)
```

For example, if i have a series (which I extracted before like this : `df['Name of the column']`) like this:  `Data = [4.0,5,3.4,'--']` the code work perfectly but if I have the data like this  `Data =[4.0,5,3.4,'--','1.45k']` it does not work.

I'm trying to change the code like this:

```
def Cleaning_strings(Data,Correction):
    for i in range(len(Data)):
        if isinstance(Data[i], float) : #Como cada dato se considera 
            Mom_Normal = Data[i]
            Correction.append(Mom_Normal)
        elif isinstance(Data[i], int): 
            Mom_Normal1 = Data[i]
            Correction.append(Mom_Normal1)
        elif isinstance(Data[i], str):
            Thousands = int(Data[i].replace('k',''))*1000
            Correction.append(Thousands)
        else:
            Zeros = int(Data[i].replace('--','0')) #No hay dato
            Correction.append(Zeros)
```

and the error that appears is:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '--'`

I understand why I get this error, but what I don't know is how I can modify the formula to make it work on this data. Please help me to find the way to replace the 'k' of the data.

Comment: a very simple solution would be to change `elif isinstance(Data[i], str):` to `elif isinstance(Data[i], str) and "k" in Data[i]:`

Comment: @vladko312 Thanks!! you are right this way it work. But also I have to change ```int(Data[i].replace('k',''))*1000 ``` for ```float(Data[i].replace('k',''))*1000```